# Laravel 5 how to return to a POST request with validation errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

I have a POST route in Laravel:

`Route::post('/quote-summary', 'QuoteController@quoteSummary')->name('quote-summary');`

On the view for this route I have a form that submits to another route:

`Route::post('/proceed-to-payment', 'QuoteController@proceedToPayment')->name('proceed-to-payment');`

Here is my controller method for `proceed-to-payment`:

```
public function proceedToPayment(Request $request) {

    if(empty($request->get('tick_statement_of_fact'))) {
        return redirect()->route('quote-summary')->with('tick_statement_of_fact', 'I am so frustrated.');


    } else {
        return view('quote.payment', compact('date_cover_required', 'expiry_date'));
    }

}
```

quoteSummary() method:

```
public function quoteSummary(QuoteRequest $request)
    {

        //dd($request);
        // get the quote
        $quote_data = $this->getQuote($request);
        $quote = number_format($quote_data, 2, '.', ',');



        if(!empty($request->get('units'))) {
            $units = $request->get('units');
        }
        if(!empty($request->get('limit_of_indemnity'))) {
            $limit_of_indemnity = number_format($request->get('limit_of_indemnity'), 2, '.', ',');
        }
        if(!empty($request->get('title'))) {
            $title = $request->get('title');
        }


        // store data in the session so we can access from generated documents
        session(['units' => $units, 'limit_of_indemnity' => $limit_of_indemnity, 'insured_name' => $insured_name, 'title' => $title, 'first_name' => $first_name, 'last_name' => $last_name, 'contact_number' => $contact_number, 'email' => $email, 'quote' => $quote]);



        return view('quote.summary');

    }
```

I am trying to redirect back to `quote-summary` but as it was a `POST` I am getting a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` as the redirect seems to be doing a `GET`.

Any ideas on how I can return to my POST route with some validation error messages?

Comment: Why would you return to a post route? You need to rethink your app structure. If you need to post something to `quote-summary` then you should add a middle step before `quote-summary` that accepts the post data, stores it (session, database, wherever) and then sends you on to `quote-summary` so that `quote-summary` is a get route.

Comment: I would return to a post route because I am validating some fields on that view and if the validation fails I need to return to that view and print out the error messages, as is self explanatory from my code.

Comment: @Styphon is right. It sounds strange. If your first post is successful, why do you need to return to this successful post after a post that's not successful?

Comment: Because the second post has a form that comes from the first post view, which may not be successful therefore I need to return to the first post view.

Comment: Ok, I suppose this is a case for front-end (toggle views), so it's simple for you to handle with.

Comment: You can't do a POST server-side redirect, for good reason too.

Answer (score 1):

Having both, post and get, routes for your quoteSummary action, would do just what you are after, i.e.:

Route::post('/quote-summary', 'QuoteController@quoteSummary')->name('quote-summary');
Route::get('/quote-summary', 'QuoteController@quoteSummary')->name('quote-summary');